# In SCRAM-SHA256 during registration, should I hash the password on client or server side?

Tags: security, passwords

I'm setting up authentication following the SCRAM model. During registration of an account, should the client send plaintext password or an already hashed password using the pbkdf2 algorithm?

The RFC does not define a user registration process. I would like to make the client never reveal his unhashed password to the server. However, I can see problems in doing so. For one, server can't verify password strength, iteration count or even the salt used. Is this an issue and how? Are there other problems I did not realise? Are there any ways of mitigating some/all of these issues?

Answer (score 0):

**Q:**  During registration of an account, should the client send plaintext password or an already hashed password using the `pbkdf2` algorithm

**A:** For security purpose, the client should **not** be generating the salt and hashing the password. It should all be done server-side mainly because the client is always on the end user's device. You never know what they are going to do to it.

That is, the client should be passing plain-text password to the server but preferably over the `TLS` protocol (https) for traffic encryption.

**Q:** I would like to make the client never reveal his unhashed password to the server, is this possible?

**A:** There is no reason to trust a client over a server.

As mentioned before, a client is much easier to be hacked than the server. If you are worried about eavesdropping then all message exchanges between the client and server should be done over the `HTTPs` protocol to ensure privacy. Again, this is covered in the first section.

Comment: First, TLS in not really an option as my connection will have to work over UDP. More importantly, in my case a server is a game server where anyone can host it, so there is all the reason in the world not to trust the server. I am asking what the consequences of hashing on client side would be, as while users can do anything they can on their side, why would they go through the hassle only to compromise **their** own security?

Comment: Ok. Then you should probably update your question to include those information. I'm not an expert in games programming but I'm not sure about doing account registration through `UDP` protocol. Typical games company would only let you register account through a website. Even if it is done within the game client, I suspect it is some form of `https` call to a server? So `TLS` is still possible

Comment: If the game server is meant to be publicly available for download and anyone can host it for others, even then you still have to trust the server right? The best you can do here is to ensure that no unhashed password is output as log messages. Release the game server as `binary` so no one can maliciously put a print statements to retrieve the unhashed password. Even then since the host has the database to the credentials, it is still possible to brute force the passwords... I think there is a limit you can do here.

Comment: Well, I wrote it would be preferable to never reveal the password to the server. I did not realize I had to explain why, as it did not seem relevant for the question. I can't make the users register through a web, as that would require the server owners to integrate the game with their websites (an they could easily modify PHP). As for releasing the server as binary, I will probably do that but that is not much protection. I wanted to force them to at least crack the hash. Brute-frocing the password is acceptable risk in this environment IMO, retrieving it in plain-text is not really.

Comment: So that is why I asked whether there is actually any greater risk by not forcing proper hashing on registration client side. As I see it, most people will not have a reason to modify and recompile the client just to decrease their own security. But is there any way the attacker could abuse this system?

Comment: Releasing the game server as a binary actually helps, if there is no source code available. It is definiltey not easy to decompile something, put in a few lines of code and recompile it back into the original binary. It is very difficult or not possible. Therefore I say it is not economical to do that and I doubt a hacker will go into such an extend of effort just to steal the passwords?

Comment: No passwords are stored in SCRAM authentication. Not even the `salted password`. The only information available to a host are the `server key`, `stored key`, `salt` and the `itr count`. Hence there is no password to be stolen from the backend. If you are still not confident, maybe you can use `bcrypt` to hash the data on the server side before storing it. This should make things very secure but some may argue it is overkill.